# jquery .load loading chart redirects and says google is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a page with many queries written in classical php. On the page i was displaying two charts. Everything worked fine. But now i have to remove these charts from the page and load them when the page finishes loading because there is too much to load already(queries etc.)   Here is what i am doing.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#charts').load('includes/charts.php');
})

<div id='charts'></div>
```

This should load charts when it finishes loading. Here is my charts.php code.

```
<?php 
    //here is some php which runs queries thats fine no problem i have checked step by step
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Calls Type', 'Call Number'],<?php echo $totalcalls ?>]);
        var options = {
            title: 'TRAFFIC SUMMARY',
            slices: {0: {color: '#006EFF'}, 1:{color: 'green'} }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 320px; height: 180px;"></div>
```

OK. If i direct call this file everything works fine but when i call it using $.load my page redirects and says google is undefined. What is the problem and why am i unable to load charts through $.load? Please help.

Comment: Not sure. But Try [this](http://pastie.org/8573543)

Comment: @Anamika this doesn't work

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery's AJAX functions, you might as well set up a data source and query that via AJAX instead of trying to load javascript via AJAX.